# How can I embed an existing multi-level drop down menu without inserting the whole code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, embed

I have a multi-level drop down menu (done using HTML + CSS) that I want to put on a number of different pages. In the future I will need to update this menu and change its contents, so I have saved the HTML in its own file so that I can roll out the changes to all the pages at once (instead of having to go through each page and repeatedly paste in the changed list items).

I have tried using iframe, but this cuts off the menu items with its limited height (setting a manual height that's big enough would leave tons of blank space, of course):

```
<iframe height="100%" src="menu.html" frameborder="no" width="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I also tried using embed (this looks fine until you mouse over the menu items -- it just scrolls within the frame):

```
<embed type="text/html" src="menu.html" width="100%" height="100%"></embed>
```

The menu functions fine when the code is simply dumped into the individual pages I need it on, so I know that's not the issue. It's the embedding and calling it from its own HTML file that is the problem. Is there a simple way to do this that will allow the drop-down menu to appear as it should?

I should mention that while I have my IT department's blessing to do this, this is a project that they aren't supporting. I can only edit the HTML of my webpages in the body, and not the head. The exception being HTML pages I upload as files (like the menu code). So there are some constraints.

Comment: Not possible with pure html. You could do this easily if you convert your site to PHP or another language that dynamically creates the pages. Not a major task for a small site as long as your server supports it.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but this is part of a major organization's website, and without IT's support (they're permitting me to do what I want within the constraints of the CMS).

So this isn't possible using a script or anything? I don't know JS at all, which is why I was hoping I just didn't know its potential role in solving the problem.

Comment: Which CMS? Is it commercial or custom?

Comment: Oracle/Stellent Site Studio. Not exactly the most intuitive system, though I'm obviously not super IT-inclined.

Comment: If you have your site live, you could use an ASP comment include. <!--#include file="url.html"-->. That should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is a bit of a long winded javascript approach that might keep your IT guys happy:

```
window.onload = new Function("load('embed-me.html','content')"); // Replace with URL of your file and ID of div you want to load into.

function ahah(url, target) {
  document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = ' Fetching data...';
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (req != undefined) {
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {ahahDone(url, target);};
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send("");
  }
}  

function ahahDone(url, target) {
  if (req.readyState == 4) { // only if req is "loaded"
    if (req.status == 200) { // only if "OK"
      document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = req.responseText;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(target).innerHTML=" AHAH Error:\n"+ req.status + "\n" +req.statusText;
    }
  }
}

function load(name, div) {
    ahah(name,div);
    return false;
}
```

Not written by me([LINK](http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/602)) (I just added the run on page load bit).

Tested and working (in Chrome at least). Though your site will have no menu if the user has javascript disabled!

EDIT:

Example...

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="embed-me.js"></script> <!-- load the javascript -->
    <div id="content"></div> <!-- html will be embedded here -->
</body>
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but once I've uploaded the .js file (I can't control anything in the head of the page), what do I run on the page itself to make the menu appear? Sorry, appreciate the help, just a bit over my head here.

Comment: Save the code in an external .js file then embed it on every page that requires the menu. <script type="text/javascript" src="embed-me.js"></script> Doesn't need to be in the head. Anywhere on the page will do.

Comment: Hmm. Still can't get it working. Just shows up blank. I uploaded the .js only changing the first line (inserting my menu URL and a div ID) -- do I insert my own URL anywhere else in the script? Also, since I'm only editing the body of the page, I named the div 'menu' and put <div id="menu><script HTML></script></div>. Does that make sense? I really appreciate the assistance, by the way.

Comment: You should place an empty div (like this <div id="menu"></div>) where ever you want the html to be embedded. Also, in my test page I stripped out all of the <head>, <body> etc. tags. That may be necessary for this to work properly. The <script> tag should not be wrapped in your <div id="menu"> but seperate from it

Comment: Looks like it's finally working! Thanks for the help again. Of course, I have one last question: there's a problem in IE8 (which my org still uses, sadly). The CSS that makes the menu look nice seems to get lost in transition, so the menu shows up as a long bulleted list. Is there a way to preserve the CSS through the script in IE8? (I can't test with IE9 here, but I'm heading home and will look at this.) Good karma heading your direction, in any case!

Comment: Hooray! The embedded HTML should pick up the CSS from the page it is loaded into. Are you definitely using the correct CSS on the page?

Comment: It worked and loaded the CSS fine in Chrome/Firefox/Opera/IE9, just not IE8. I added the CSS <link> code again right before the <script> and <div> code and it now renders fine in IE8 (and the rest). So mission accomplished. Thanks again -- really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I use the following php code and works very nice. It doesn't even show when you check the source code online.

```
    <?php include("menu.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php Include !!

Okay first.. copy the menu code and save it on to a file called **menu-1.php**

then whenever you want to use your menu; just type the following code:

```
<?php include("menu-1.php"); ?>
```

This is a good way to do menu's because every time you need to update your menu, you wont have to update every single page, just update your menu-1.php

P.S. PHP might not show up on your local machine unless you are using wamp or xamp