# How To Include Files In Tumblr Theme

Tags: php, html, layout, include, tumblr

I'm working on a new layout for my design portfolio and since I want to have a blog as well, I'm just making the whole thing in Tumblr. I want to use something like PHP or HTML includes for the header and footer so I don't have to edit 15 pages of headers and footers whenever I make a change, but the problem is Tumblr doesn't allow either PHP or HTML includes (I've tried both and the code just doesn't render). I thought of using iframes, but after some experimentation, those just aren't going to work the way I need them to.

So my question is- is there any way I can create my header and footer files, host them on a different site and then call up the file in my Tumblr layout? I've spent several hours over the last few days scouring the internet and have not been ble to come up with anything. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: You could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439405/how-can-i-embed-an-existing-multi-level-drop-down-menu-without-inserting-the-who/11440141#comment15118980_11440141

Comment: Is this question really suited for SO?

Comment: @PhpMyCoder I didn't know where else to ask- I never get any results on Yahoo!Answers, nobody responds when I make a blog post, none of my facebook friends would even know what I'm talking about and there's no help forum for tumblr. I can send the support team a message via tumblr, but it could be days before I hear back and I'm just not willing to wait that long. So in short, I didn't know where else to ask and I like SO, so yeah. I came here. If you would be able to direct me to another website dedicated specifically for tumblr help and support, I will go there instead in the future.

Comment: @3rror404 Yeah, that's a PHP include which I already tried and the code doesn't render. But thanks though :-)

Comment: @JenniferNiles Sorry. Re-reading my comment made it sound really aggressive. I wasn't sure. I meant to sound questioning (which is why I didn't flag to relocate it). There are Facebook API questions on here so Tumblr is probably appropriate too. I also don't want to become one of those SO users who flags everything.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder No worries :-) I honestly just didn't know if there was a better place to ask. But, I think I've gotten my answer which is a big fat "it can't be done". Oh well!

Comment: @jennifer niles My answer in that thread was JavaScript not PHP

Comment: @JenniferNiles 3rror404 was actually linking to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11440141/568785

Comment: @JenniferNiles No one question has not helped?

Answer (score 3):

> “I want to use something like PHP or HTML includes for the header and footer so I don't have to edit 15 pages of headers and footers whenever I make a change,”

*Tumblr themes* system provide only **one template for all pages**. That's why when you will edit header for *one page*, you will edit it for **all pages**

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Tumblr will allow you to do that, simply for security reasons. It's been a while since I used the blogging site, but when I was using it, it seemed pretty limited as far as getting really deep with the HTML or any other coding.

Comment: It's not an answer I like, but one I will have to live with I suppose. Thanks :-)